# Protractor exactBinding for directive binding

Tags: angularjs, protractor

Using protractor...I am trying to get the binding of `sort-property='name'`. The issue I am having though is `exactBinding` is not finding it. How can I make it to where `exactBinding` grabs this binding?

```
.directive('rxSortableColumn', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'templates/rxSortableColumn.html',
        transclude: true,
        scope: {
            sortMethod: '&',
            sortProperty: '@',
            predicate: '=',
            reverse: '='
        }
    };
})


<rx-sortable-column sort-property="name" predicate="sort.predicate" reverse="sort.reverse" class="ng-isolate-scope"></rx-sortable-column>

element.all(By.exactBinding('name'))
```

Answer (score 1):

`by.exactBinding`, as well as `by.binding`, would only look through the elements having `ng-binding` class ([source](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/8a3412e98614bb69978869b34b5b7243619f015d/lib/clientsidescripts.js#L61)).

In your case, get the element `by.css`:

```
by.css("[sort-property=name]")
```

Comment: isn't `sortProperty` a ng-binding?

Comment: @dman could you show how the `rx-sortable-column` is presented on the page? Thanks.

Comment: `<rx-sortable-column sort-property="name" predicate="sort.predicate" reverse="sort.reverse" class="ng-isolate-scope"></rx-sortable-column>`

Comment: @dman nope, you cannot use `by.binding` or `by.exactBinding` here.